# Is there a tool that allows for changing the time in a GPS file?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, gps

I have a GPS tracked stored in a GPX file. Now I'm looking for a tool that allows me to set the start time of the track and the duration, and the tool should automatically evenly distribute the appropriate timestamps for all my recorded points in the track.

The tool should be free and run on OSX.

Comment: Why should the tool be free exactly?

Comment: Because I like it that way. But if I can't find anything else, I would also be fine with another one.

Comment: Ok, good luck :)

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: So let’s say your original GPS recording was 1 hr long and you have 10 points. Do you want a) proportional scaling to arbitrary time length (*relative* time distances do not change) or b) redistribute the time distance so that the time between GPS points is evenly distributed? (one point every 6 minutes)

Comment: @myhd both is ok for me.

Comment: Surprised you are fine with both alternatives … let’s say I am trying to find out what your actual plan, your original problem is. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @myhd Ok, let me describe the problem in more detail: From time to time, I go running the same route. I measure the time to see if I improve. To measure both the time and the distance, I use an app on my phone. The captured tracks I store on my computer. Now it happens, that a few days ago, the app wasn't able to record the tour. So that I nevertheless have the route stored on my computer, I planned to use an old recording and just adapt the time. I know how long it took me, and I'm interested in the total time and not in the time for each data point.

Answer (score 3):

I'm certain that tool does not exist. That being said, you can open the .gpx file in TextWrangler (free) and view the time stamps and edit them. They are in the XML format:

`<time>2013-03-21T18:04:36Z</time>`

I dont see why you couldn't import them into an excel spreadsheet and alter the times with an algoritm that would add a specific quantity to each. But I wouldn't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

GPX stores `dateTime` in UTC, so if you modify the timestamps they will no longer be accurate. The tool you are planning to import this data into should handle offsetting or translating to local time.

For example: Adze http://kobotsw.com/apps/adze/